# jQuery Validate checkbox checked required?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validation plugin to validate a form.

The problem is that I can't find a way to validate if a single checkbox in my form  is checked

HTML markup:

```
<label for="terms">terms : </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms">
```

jQuery code:

```
rules: {
    terms: "required"
},
messages:{
    terms: "check the checbox"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What plugin are you talking about. Do you mean *J*Query?

Comment: @IanClark He said jQuery in the title, in the middle of the question, and the tags. Any reasonable reader would realize that the missing j in the first line is just a typo.

Comment: Sorry I missed the tags - I saw you added jQuery validate in an edit. I wasn't trying to be pedantic.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe your checkbox has css style

```
display: none
```

Replace it with

```
visibility: hidden;
width: 0;
```

It helped to me.

Answer (score 5):

HTML markup:

```
<label for="terms">terms : </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="1" id="terms">
```

jQuery code:

```
rules: {
    terms: {
       required : true
    }

},
messages:{
    terms: {
        required : "check the checbox"
    }
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mZ6zJ/

Answer (score 4):

You need to give a value to the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="terms" value="accepted">
```

Comment: This did not solve my problem.
I decided to tackle it in another way - I disable the submit button if checkbox is unchecked. 
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

**Example of Checkbox Jquery Validation**

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="demo">
<label for="terms">terms : </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="terms[]" value="your value" id="terms">
</form>
```

- give Checkbox name with square brackets.
- Provide Value to Checkbox compulsory.

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#demo").validate({
         rules: {
               'terms[]': { required: true },
         },
         messages:{
               'terms[]': "check the checbox"
         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code in the document ready jQuery method and a validate check:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('#formId').validate({
     rules: {
         terms: "required"
      },
      messages:{
         terms: "check the checbox"
      }
   })
})
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score -4):

I simply made my own annotation in C# and matched it with my jQuery validation.  Now I just annotate any checkbox where this comes up.  If you aren't using C# you can easily just add the class on element you wanted it applied to.

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CheckboxRequired : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(bool) || (bool)value == true)
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        return new ValidationResult("This checkbox must be checked.");
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = "This checkbox must be checked.",
            ValidationType = "CheckboxRequired"
        };
        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

And in my Validation.js

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("CheckboxRequired", function (value, element) {
return (value != typeof undefined && value != false);});
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("CheckboxRequired", { CheckboxRequired: true});
```