# jQuery validations => checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I've been searching for a way to produce a "Required", jQuery message on a "Checkbox" form input type.

All others are OK, the standard "Text" input type, the "Select" input type, the "Radio-button" input type. But I don't have yet the "Checkbox" input type.

Where would I place a: `data-val="true" data-val-required="Please check at least one"` in the following block?

Or maybe there is some "prep" syntax first?

```
  <script src="/forms/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script src="/forms/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

  <form>
  <...>
  <td valign="top">
    <input type="checkbox" name="audience" value="executives" >Executives <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="audience" value="professionals">Professionals<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="audience" value="practitioners">Practitioners

    <div class="col-sm-1 input">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.audience)</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate checkbox checked required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203866/jquery-validate-checkbox-checked-required)

Answer (score 0):

The key is to submit the form via code only after you've validated that the checkbox is checked. It displays a message and will not submit the form if the checkbox is not checked.

```
<form asp-action="Request">
    @*This is a work-around for a checkbox bug*@
    <style>
        .custom-control-label::before,
        .custom-control-label::after {
            top: .8rem;
            width: 1.25rem;
            height: 1.25rem;
        }
    </style>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="IAgree" type="checkbox" id="TermsCheck1" value="false" onclick="$('#Terms').hide();" />
        <input asp-for="IAgree" type="checkbox" id="TermsCheck2" value="false" onclick="$('#Terms').hide();" />

        <div id="Terms">Please confirm.</div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" onclick="ValidateTerms()">
            Continue
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        function ValidateTerms() {
            if ($('#TermsCheck1').prop('checked') || $('#TermsCheck2').prop('checked')) {
                $('form:first').submit();
            }
            else {
                $("#Terms").show();
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: @Antoine Maréchal - If this answer helped to solve your problem please "Accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark. This will give future readers confidence that the answer is worth a try. It will also give me, the one who answered, addition reputation points. Thanks and good luck on your future programming efforts.